# getting return values from python consolemenu

Tags: python

How do I work with any of the user selected values, or the return values of the function calls in consolemenu items?

I have determined that I can check if the menu is alive, but I'm not sure how to interrogate this and look for actions, return values or selections.

[based on the usage example provided at PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/console-menu/),

```
from consolemenu import *
from consolemenu.items import *

import logging
logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def add(number):
    return number+number

m = ConsoleMenu('Title')
item = MenuItem('Item one')
item_two = MenuItem('Item Two')
func = FunctionItem('add numbers', add, [5])

m.append_item(item)
m.append_item(item_two)
m.append_item(func)
logging.debug('starting up')
m.start()

while m.is_alive():
    # this is where the work gets done, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.
    pass

m.join()
```

There are plenty of examples in the documentation that show super basic methods for getting one-shot responses from users, but I can't lay my hands on a working example that shows how to work with a running menu.

Comment: You don't *need* to "look for actions" - every menu item that specifies an action includes a function to perform that action (such as `add()` in your example), THAT is "where the work gets done".  It's pointless to return anything from such functions, they should do everything needed (such as displaying the results) themselves.

Comment: @jasonharper That makes some sense, but I need to build menus based on choices users make; the results of a function need to feed back into my main process and trigger adding more options to the menu or sub menus (e.g. listing files in from a selected directory). How do I do this without making all my variables globals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this too, this is the solution I came up with:

The easiest way to get access to a running menu is likely to overwrite the `action` method of the `FunctionItem`.

```
from consolemenu import *
from consolemenu.items import *

import logging

logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class MyFunctionItem(FunctionItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def action(self):
        super().action()
        result = self.get_return()
        item_three = MenuItem(f"Result: {result}")
        m.append_item(item_three)


def add(number):
    return number + number


m = ConsoleMenu("Title")
item = MenuItem("Item one")
item_two = MenuItem("Item Two")
func = MyFunctionItem("add numbers", add, [5])

m.append_item(item)
m.append_item(item_two)
m.append_item(func)
logging.debug("starting up")

m.show()
```

This way there is also no need for the nasty busy loop.